# Should I use an array or object to reference system settings?

Tags: php

I am building a site that has 30-40 system settings. These are editable in a text file. I want to make sure that I set the site up with the most logical and less resource-intensive method of pulling these settings.

I have been thinking about using an array:

```
$system['language'] = 'en';
$system['version'] = '0.1';
```

And referencing them throughout the site like: `echo $system['version'];`

Or, I can set them up as an object:

```
class SiteConfig {
  public $language = 'en';
  public $version = '0.1';
}

$system = new SiteConfig;
```

And referencing them throughout the site like: `echo $system->version;`

Which is best to use, or does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: Did you though about a database?

Comment: No for now this is all from a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach taken by some frameworks (Laravel for example) is to create a settings file, that you pull in with `require`.

Your various settings are all defined in that file in a single array, that  is returned:

settings.php

```
<?php

return array(
    'language' => 'en',
    'version'  => '0.1',
    'timezone' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',
);
```

Then you can use it like:

```
$system = require 'settings.php';
echo $system['version'];
```

See example #5 on the [php.net docs for `include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for more about this return.